# Can any of these VB.Net snippets be reduced to 1 line?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

I have :

- Snippet 1:

  ```
  For Each sheet In WB.Sheets
      wbSheetNames.Add(sheet.Name)
  Next sheet
  ```
- Snippet 2:

  ```
  For i = 0 To sheetNames.Count - 1
      wb.Sheets(i + 2).Name = sheetNames(i).Replace(currMonth, nextMonth)
  Next
  ```
- Snippet 3:

  ```
   For Each cell In row
        If cell.Formula.Contains(nameString) Then
             downRange(sheet, cell.Address()).Value = downRange(sheet, cell.Address()).Value
        End If
   Next cell
  ```
- Snippet 4:

  ```
  For Each sheet In sheetsToDelete
     sheet.Activate()
     sheet.Delete()
  Next sheet
  ```

Is there some construct or method that can do these in 1 line?

**Note:**
All the snippets are different and should not be clubbed. These are the situations where I think there might be a smarter way of doing these simple tasks.

Comment: Put all statements on a single line with a `:` between them?

Comment: Its a good tip, but this is not what I meant !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, found no way to reduce any template.

Used the `:` trick at some places.. Thanx for that !

Answer (score 1):

Using some LINQ could possibly make some of them use fewer lines, but most of them would not be very readable. You should be writing code for maintainability, not just for getting the job done. If you're thinking about performance: using as few lines as possible is not really a good indication for optimization.

Snippet 1 by itself could be reduced to a single line, assuming wbSheetNames is a List of String:

```
wbSheetNames.AddRange(WB.Sheets.Select(Function(x) x.Name))
```

Improvement? Not really. You could remove the list allocation not part of the snippet by using something like:

```
wbSheetNames = WB.Sheets.Select(Function(x) x.Name).ToList()
```

This is arguably a slight improvement over the original.

That being said: it looks like you might be able to combine snippet 1 and 2, saving the allocation of a temporary list. The exact intend of the code is not clear to me however. Somewhere along the way you are adding 2 sheets? Otherwise I would think that `wb.Sheets(i + 2)` will go out of range.

Comment: No, All snippets are different and not to be combined.

Comment: I want to do these simple obvious tasks in a smarter way, like what a pro would do.

Comment: I feel there must be constructs in vb.net that could do these obvious tasks in a more direct way.

Comment: @Yugal: what a pro would do, is to create their own reusable helper method if they find they're repeating themselves :)

Comment: What are helper methods ? Can you please guide me ?

Comment: @Yugal: in this case, I don't see anything that warrants creating any helper methods.

Comment: `wbSheetNames.AddRange(WB.Sheets.Select(Function(x) x.Name))` and `wbSheetNames = WB.Sheets.Select(Function(x) x.Name).ToList()` both gives error i.e. Expression does not produce a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) extension method.

Comment: show some code.. I know there are some existing constructs that can do this, but I am not sure how to use them.